# I can not open my blog

Tags: 2010, blog

I am using SharePoint 2010 and I created a new blog. I already have several posts added. I was able to open each of the post but now when I try to open a specific post, I am directed to the Comments page and no to my main post page.

The main page of the blog ends with `....TeamBlog/default.aspx`

And when I click on a specific post, the address bar states  `.../TeamBlog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=10`

Is there a setting to configure I want to open the post directly and not the comment? 
How can I fix this problem ?